# Custom UIPicker - Placing an image, text and subtext in one row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I've got the UIPicker working perfectly. Only problem being not only do I need text for each row but I also need an image on the left side of the text and some extra subtext under the main text. I have no idea how to do this so I was hoping someone might point me in the right direction? I'd really appreciate it. Here is how it is supposed to look:

[image]

Comment: try this: https://github.com/nicklockwood/CountryPicker

Comment: Thank you Mr.T! That subclass works like magic.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the project called "CountryPickerDemo" that Mr.T linked to (take a look at it!) I realized the core method for making a picture & text appear in one row is:

**-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view**

Here is how I made it work in my code:

```
//Custom view and rows are created inside this method. There doesn't seem to be an easier way.
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    //IF view doesn't exist, then create it.
    if (!view)
    {
        //View creation.
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 30)]; //(0, 0, 280, 30)]; //x & y   width & height

        //Rows label creation.
        UILabel *label          = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 110, 24)]; //(35, 3, 245, 24)];
        label.textColor         = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.tag               = 1;
        [view addSubview:label];

        //Rows image creation.
        UIImageView *imgView   = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)]; //(3, 3, 24, 24)];
        imgView.contentMode    = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imgView.tag            = 2;
        [view addSubview:imgView];
    }

    //INPUT data into rows. P.S. I have TWO components; not just one like in the picture above. If you only need one component like in the picture above, then ignore the IF ELSE statements and just use the code inside the IF statement only.
    if (component == 0)
    {
        //Load actual text into 1st label sections.
        ((UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:1]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _componentOne[row]];

        //Load actual images into 1st image sections.
        ((UIImageView*)[view viewWithTag:2]).image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        //Load actual text into 2nd label sections.
        ((UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:1]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _componentTwo[row]];

        //Load actual images into 2nd image sections.
        ((UIImageView*)[view viewWithTag:2]).image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
    }



    //EXAMPLE CODE.    
    //((UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:1]).text       = [[self class] countryNames][(NSUInteger)row];

    //NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CountryPicker.bundle/%@", [[self class] countryCodes][(NSUInteger) row]];
    //((UIImageView*)[view viewWithTag:2]).image  = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];


    return view;
}
```

**NOTE:** Type your own image name into the placeholder @"imageName.png" to see how it looks. Placing different images, by maybe using an array, is your deal to figure out.